# CMD: Reemplazar partes de string dentro de un fichero txt

Tags: windows, cmd, txt

Tengo el fichero fichero1.txt con el siguiente contenido:

29-Mar-20 00:00,22.278,95

29-Mar-20 01:01,22.278,24

29-Mar-20 03:05,22.278,45

29-Mar-20 04:10,22.278,12

29-Mar-20 05:12,22.278,46

29-Mar-20 06:15,22.278,47

29-Mar-20 07:53,22.279,45

Quiero reemplazar la primera coma por un ;

He intentado con el siguiente comando:

powershell -Command "(gc ./output.csv) -replace ',', ';' | Out-File -encoding ASCII ./output.csv"

Pero me cambia la coma del final también, por lo que no me vale.

He pensado que tal vez se podría hacer de la siguiente manera:

powershell -Command "(gc ./output.csv) -replace ':%%,', ';' | Out-File -encoding ASCII ./output.csv"

Siendo los % un carácter cualquiera, de esta forma me editaría siempre la coma que quiero. Pero el % no hace lo que creo que hace y estoy un poco perdido.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo

Comment: Te gustaria tratar el fichero ```csv``` y que todas  las filas que tienes te la reemplace? igual de otra manera para  que te des una idea con ```$string =  '29-Mar-20 07:53,22.279,45'``` con un ```replace``` se podría hacer ``` $string -replace ',',';' ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he solucionado el problema.

Solo hay que sustituir los %% del ejemplo de arriba por el carácter wildcard de batch "."

powershell -Command "(gc ./output.csv) -replace ':..,', ';' | Out-File -encoding ASCII ./output.csv"

Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Yo tengo una duda: Como podria diferenciar entre "a" y "A" Porque lo que quiero es que solo se sustitullan las "a" Gracias, por leer.

Comment: No me funciona, Lo que necesito es por ejemplo en este txt: Hola mundo, yo y carlos hemos comido muy bien en un restaurante, hoy ha sido un dia muy bueno. Cambiar la "H" por "HHH", y la "h" por "hhh" gracias.